# Issue with google-map-react package - Unable to set custom center coordinates

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, google-map-react

This component passes in the address then uses another API to get the latitude and longitude. The latitude and longitude are then passed into the google-map-react API to be converted into a map.

But I'm unable to set custom center coordinates for the map. I have set up the `fetchAddress` function to retrieve the latitude and longitude coordinates for a specific address using the Google Geocoding API. However, when I log the `defaultProps.center` object, it shows two objects, one with default values (lat: 60, lng: 30) and another with the correct values (e.g., lat: -33.9325244, lng: 151.1787937).

And I want to use the correct latitude and longitude values from the Geocoding API response to set the center of the map. But when I pass in latitude and longitude values into it, it only handles the default values: lat: 60, lng: 30.

Here is my code:

```
import { AppContainer, Title, Image } from './styledMapApp'; 
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; 
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react'; 
import axios from 'axios';

const MapApp = ({ location }: { location?: string }) => {   
const apiKey = 'mykey';   
const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState<number>(60);   
const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState<number>(30);   
const testingAddress = 'Arrivals Hall, Sydney International Airport, NSW 2020';   const encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(testingAddress);

  const fetchAddress = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={${encodedAddress}&key=${apiKey}`
      );
      const address = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
      const currentLatitude = address.lat;
      const currentLongitude = address.lng;

      setLatitude(currentLatitude);
      setLongitude(currentLongitude);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }   };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAddress();   }, []);

  const defaultProps = {
    zoom: 11,   };
  console.log(latitude);
  console.log(longitude);

  return (
    <AppContainer>
      <Title>MapApp</Title>
      <div style={{ height: '30vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: apiKey }}
          defaultCenter={{ lat: latitude, lng: longitude }}
          defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
        ></GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    </AppContainer>   ); }; export default MapApp;
```

When I do: `console.log(latitude); console.log(longitude);`
I can see on the console that my object

```
60.      MapApp.tsx:36 
30.      MapApp.tsx:37 
-33.9325244.     MapApp.tsx:36 
151.1793765.     MapApp.tsx:37
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

### You should not modify the `defaultCenter` prop and set a `center` prop instead

I can see that you are using the `google-map-react` library. And what you were trying to do is modify the `defaultCenter` prop of the `<GoogleMapReact />` component. Which is something you should not do.

As per this [Library's documentation](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/HEAD/API.md#defaultcenter-array-or-object), `defaultCenter` is the,

> Default lat/lng at which to center the map - **changing this prop throws a warning**

So what you should use instead is the `center` prop which is described as a,

> Lat/lng at which to center the map

In your case, you can just create an object variable for the `defaultCenter` instead of separating the `latitude` and `longitude` like you did:

```
const defaultCenter = { lat: 60, lng: 30 };
```

Then create another object for the `center` props with `useState` so that you can modify the center of your map whenever you like:

```
const [center, setCenter] = useState("Center has not bee updated yet");
```

Notice that I just put a string first that says: *"Center has not bee updated yet"* since this will be updated later by your `fetch` call to the **Geocoding API**.

Then in your `fetch` call, since the `response.data.results[0].geometry.location` is already a `latLng` object, you can just directly use the variable you saved it to called `address` and use it in your `setCenter` function to update the `center` state variable. Your `fetch` call should look like this:

```
const fetchAddress = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={${encodedAddress}&key=${apiKey}`
    );
    const address = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
    setCenter(address);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

You can optionally create another `useEffect` with `center` state as its depency to check whenever the center value changes when rendering your component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Default center is: ");
    console.log(defaultCenter);
    console.log("Center has now been updated by the fetch request");
    console.log(center);
  }, [center]);
```

Then lastly, your `<GoogleMapReact />` component should have the `center` prop, and it should look like this:

```
<GoogleMapReact
    center={center}
    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: apiKey }}
    defaultCenter={defaultCenter}
    defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
></GoogleMapReact>
```

With this, your map should update to the `latLng` that your `fetch` call obtained through **Geocoding**.

Here's a proof of concept sandbox that you can play around with and check (*Just use your own API key and make sure it is restricted to avoid compromise.* :>): https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-with-google-map-react-package-unable-to-set-custom-center-coordinates-vp5n7t?file=/src/App.tsx

I hope this helps!